# Proof Verification : Ex 14, Section 3.1, Sequences and Series, Intro to Real Analysis, Bartle

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to know, if my proof to the below problem is correct.

> 14. Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $0<b<1$. Show that $\lim(nb^n)=0$. Hint: Use the binomial theorem as in example 3.1.11(d).

**Proof.**

We can express,

$b^n=\frac{1}{(1+a)^n}$ where $a>0$.

The expression $(1+a)^n$ can be written as,

$\begin{align}
(1+a)^n&=1+na+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2+\ldots\\
&\ge1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
\therefore{nb^n}&\le\frac{n}{1+a^2\cdot{n(n-1)/2}}\\
&<\frac{n}{a^2\cdot{n(n-1)/2}}\\
&=\frac{2}{a^2}\frac{1}{(n-1)}
\end{align}$

$\therefore{|nb^n-0|<C\cdot{a_{n}}}$ where, $C=2/a^2$ and the sequence $(a_{n}):=1/(n-1)$ approaches $0$, as $n$ becomes large.

Hence, $\lim(nb^n)=0$.

Comment: It looks fine to me. This is a typical question asked in interviews, by the way.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Interviews for what?

Comment: Well, I knew a person who was interviewed for a scholarship exam, and later for a job interview in IT. I don't know why he got a question very similar to this, but he did, and I don't know what applications they have in whatever he's going to do in his job. By "know", I mean he was on Stack Exchange about 6 months back and mentioned all this in his question, which was heavily down voted. I being the good boy that time answered it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Can i answer by saying that the limit of sequence is zero because the series is convergent? i think of derivative of geometric series or something

Comment: @BCLC You mean $\sum nb^n < \infty$, therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} nb^n = 0$? Makes sense to me.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks XD hope to ace those interviews. merry christmas, happy new year, and happy holidays!

Comment: @BCLC Not quite my holiday right now (I am working right now) but same to you, and hope you do well, looking forward to meeting you on the site again!